# Agregar botón en menú de navigation Drawer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer

quisiera agregar un botón en el menú de navigation drawer , estube intentando crear un nuevo item en el nav_header_main y dandole la propiedad de un button pero no resulto ,¿Como agregaría un botón en mi menú desplegable?

**algo así**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*agregue un item nuevo*

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/salir"
    android:title=""
    android:actionLayout="@layout/button_salir"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

*creé un xml button pero , al agregarlo en el item no me muestra el botom*

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:text="Login"
android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

*y donde iría su código. Gracias por la ayuda :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo hice una vez, pero en lugar de un botón usé TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer_drawer" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/logout"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>




</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

y en mi activity agregué lo siguiente

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    nav_view.logout.setOnClickListener(this)
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.logout ->{
                Log.d(TAG,"on click logout")
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: danms07 gracias , me solucionaste el problema